# After transition from CVCS to DVCS , what problems were solved? what still remain unsolved?

Tags: version-control, dvcs, cvcs

After transition from Centralized Version Control System(CVCS) to Distruted Version Control System(DVCS), what problems were solved? What still remain unsolved?

Answer (score 0):

DVCS proponents point to several advantages of distributed version control systems over the traditional centralised model:

- Allows users to work productively when not connected to a network.
- Makes most operations much faster.
- Allows participation in projects without requiring permissions from project authorities
- Allows private work, so users can use their changes even for early drafts they do not want to publish.
- Avoids relying on one physical machine as a single point of failure.
- Permits centralized control of the "release version" of the project
- On FLOSS (free/libre and open-source software) software projects it is much easier to create a project fork from a project that is stalled because of leadership conflicts or design disagreements.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Distributed_vs._centralized)